# what is an example of a table in Unnormalised Form that contains at least 10 attributes with at least one 1:1, one 1:n and one n:m relation

Tags: database

ome up with your initial table in Unnormalised Form (UNF). Your table should contain at least 10 attributes(columns) and 10 rows.
It should furthermore contain at least one 1:1, one 1:n and one n:m relation.
Argue why this is in UNF and explain where the relations can be found. Remember data is not self-explanatory but depends upon context. Please make it unambiguous.

ome up with your initial table in Unnormalised Form (UNF). Your table should contain at least 10 attributes(columns) and 10 rows.
It should furthermore contain at least one 1:1, one 1:n and one n:m relation.
Argue why this is in UNF and explain where the relations can be found. Remember data is not self-explanatory but depends upon context. Please make it unambiguous.

Comment: So user (name First/Last), , phone# (could have more than 1), Phone Type, Email (could have more than 1) , (Email Type), Schools Attended (could have more than one and could be shared both other people), School Type(s)  Now think about populating those values and how you would abstract each out into seperate tables so you achieved at least 3rd normal form.  That would explain why it's UNF

Comment: Also consider the key's for each.  Does a persons name make a good key?  (what happens if they get married, have a name change)  should you have start/end dates on each of the "records" so you know when they were called what or does that matter?  (so context and requirements as to why you're recording name become important.  Just some food for thought.